# Gatling compilation failed

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling

I'm trying to build https://github.com/gatling/gatling but the compilation fails. The steps I undertook:

1. Installed sbt using the [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html).
2. Clone the [github project](https://github.com/gatling/gatling).
3. Execute `sbt compile` in the directory `gatling`.

I get the following error:

```
[error] /home/groot/gatling/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling

/commons/util/Arrays.scala:36:32: macro implementation not found: cfor
[error] (the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)
[error]     cfor(length)(_ > 1, _ - 1) { i =>
[error]                                ^
[error] /home/groot/gatling/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling/commons/util/StringHelper.scala:40:23: macro implementation not found: fast
[error] (the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)
[error]   val EmptyFastring = fast""
[error]                       ^
[error] /home/groot/gatling/gatling-commons/src/main/scala/io/gatling/commons/validation/package.scala:38:20: macro implementation not found: info
[error] (the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)
[error]         logger.info(message, e)
[error]                    ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (gatling-commons / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed May 4, 2018, 11:30:14 AM
```

I do not know enough of scala to debug this, how can I fix this?

Comment: Check this from the scala lang doc: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I've executed as `sudo` (`sudo sbt compile`) and now the compilation is succesful.

Comment: You should never have to do that. That indicates a permissions problem on your project. Delete the gatling directory using `sudo rm -rf gatling` and start again, to avoid this problem.

Comment: As @RobinGreen, Never call `sbt` from `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Try IntelliJ Idea with scala plugin
Just use IntelliJ Idea open the project folder